# JavaScript and DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I can't understand such situation:

I have a site template and in header there is code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#header').corner();
    ...
}
```

`corner()` is just a jQuery-plugin function. But the problem is:

```
("#header") is null
    $('#header').corner();
```

It works at main page, but at another one (with the same template) - doesn't work.

To view everything in action, look at [this](http://umestentorg.ru/) page. You will see header (blue top div) rounded and there aren't any errors in firebug console. Now go to [this](http://umestentorg.ru/catalog.php?SECTION_ID=139) page. Everything works too, but this time that's not the main page (it still uses same template file).

And the [third page](http://umestentorg.ru/catalog.php?SECTION_ID=109&ELEMENT_ID=1292), the error appears there but still the same template. What's wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that [$ is a stupid name a for a function](http://blog.dorward.me.uk/2009/02/19/the-dollar-function-must-die.html).

On the third page, `$` is defined by jQuery and redefined by Prototype. You are getting conflicts.

Start by rewriting all your jQuery stuff to use `jQuery` instead of `$` and call [`noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

Comment: Dont rewrite the jQuery stuff. Decided to either use jQuery or Prototype. Using two different DOM libraries is simply stupid.

Answer (score 1):

A good solution is to use namespacing for your scripts like this to avoid naming conflicts as Quentin already mentioned.

You can still use $ by doing the following:

```
(function($) {
  //your code goes here and can use $ as jQuery without interfering with Prototype
} (jQuery));
```

This way you never have to use $ directly while being able to selectively use $.

Answer (score 1):

If you type into your `console`:

```
$.toString();
```

You'll see that some script, somewhere overwrites the jQuery shortcut `$`. That is most likely the reason for that error. To solve that, create a wrapper context for your whole code:

```
(function( $ ) {
    $(document).ready() {
        $('#header')....
    });
}(jQuery));
```

That will guarantee that the `$` symbol now refers the `jQuery` object, within that function context.

Comment: There's a more concise way of writing that. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897742/javascript-and-dom/6897965#6897965)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you have a name collision with Prototype. The easiest way to fix this is:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#header').corner();
    ...
});
```